# datetimepicker for jquerymobile 1.2

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I am looking for a good datetimepicker plugin for the latest jQuery mobile. My app is using phonegap. Can anybody suggest one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

googled JQM datepicker... first result...[JQM-datebox examples](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)

Comment: glad to help, feel free to accept this answer if you feel it has solved your problem...

Comment: @mr_lewjam I seem to only get the addon working if I have a custom build of JQM 1.2.0 which leaves the slider out.

Answer (score 0):

I just built one for both date and time with two flips

https://github.com/ngethe/jQM-DateBoxNgethe